# How to import key to wallet using api

Tags: eosio.token, wallet, api, private-key

I want to import the key generated from the mnemonic to the wallet of eosio server using the api.
Please let me know the api like the work on the following cmd.

`cleos wallet import *********************`

Comment: Please leave a bit more information for us. How did you generate it? Can you give an example of the key format (do not share your actual key)?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.